# Paypal IPN database error

Tags: php, sql-server, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been testing the paypal IPN using the simulator. What I get the reply back saying IPN sent successfully however it's not inserting the data into my mssql database.

MSSQL 2008, Table name = PAYPAL_IPN and only 2 columns ("ID", "accept")

```
    $msquerys="insert into PAYPAL_IPN (ID, accept) VALUES ('1', '".$payment_status."')";
$msresultss=odbc_exec($conn4,$msquerys);
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) { }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You sure `$payment_status` is `accept`? You need to echo odbc_error.

Comment: I have used .$payment_status as a value to be inserted into the table. other than that I can change it to whatever, I am only testing right now, I will be making a full table for it once I get this simple insert right.

Comment: You need to provide the error message. There are way too many variables for error. Is the table built correctly? Are the columns of the correct value type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before executing your code you should add the following code to get the status of your IPN variables.

```
$IPN = serialize($_REQUEST);
mail('your-email-address','IPN varaibles',$IPN);
```

In this way you will get the all IPN variables, Now you will get the hint for what should you do to fix this. If you are able to share your full codes, I can help to fix this